# Table cell text has extra characters

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I was trying to do some data validation on a simple printable form I created. While trying to see if a particular cell had a certain length I was surprised to see that 2 extra characters were showing up in the cells. The code I am using to get the data is

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(5, 1).Range.Text
```

Those characters appear to be [ANSI](http://ascii-table.com/ascii.php) codes 13 and 7 which correspond to Line Feed and Bell. Are these codes just standard when using tables in Word?

How can I work with this? Is there a different property I can look at? Do I need to just accept their presence and account for it exclusively?

**Note:** I am aware I am not using absolute references in my code sample. This is just an example to prove a point.

Answer (score 1):

Those are the standard characters that appear at the end of a table cell. They can be annoying to work around, but usually something like

```
objRng.MoveEndWhile Chr(7) & Chr(13), wdBackward
```

does the trick.